# In Python 2.7, is it necessary to import submodules explicitly?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This code fails:

```
import setuptools.command
setuptools.command.install.install

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'install'
```

But this works:

```
import setuptools.command.install
setuptools.command.install.install

<class setuptools.command.install.install at 0x7f2355911328>
```

Where *install* is a class of the *install* submodule of the *command* submodule of *setuptools*.

Setuptools version is 2.2 but I've tried with a dummy python project and I get the same behaviour, so I'm not sure this is setuptools-specific.

I've noticed this after an Ubuntu upgrade (which took me from python 2.7.4 to 2.7.6). I'm  convinced the first snippet did work pre-upgrade but haven't been able to find anything relevant in the python release notes.

Oddly enough, this seems to behave differently with the *os* package:

```
import os
os.path.join

<function join at 0x7f9f4be6fc80>
```

My question: When using functionality that lives inside a submodule of a different package, do you need to import the submodule explicitly always? If so, why does this not affect os? Otherwise, how to tell whether I need to do it or not?

Comment: Yes, packages do not auto-import contained modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.path` is special. In the `os` module, it injects `os.path` into `sys.modules`. See https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Lib/os.py#L119

So in general, you always need to import the submodules.